# Designing long running background jobs that are part of domain language

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, abstraction

I am going to type out my problem in terms of my domain use case;

When an Operator has an Ingest with a valid Dataset (Lowside, Drive and EntryPoints selected), they will opt to then Scan the Ingest. The Scan will run over all the EntryPoints in the Ingests Dataset. A series of antivirus and content scans will occur - notably

ClamAV
Sophos AV
Trend AV
Apache Tika
If these scans detect any Threats, the Ingest has failed and the Operator should be able to see more information about the Threats; what Scan detected them and any Logs produced by the scanners. No more actions should be allowed to take place on the Ingest - it will become archived. To progress the Ingest, an entirely new Ingest should be created."""

I have highlighted words that I believe stick out as domain concepts.

My trouble is in actually designing the scans themselves. These scans can take in the order of days to complete, thus must be off loaded to another process - thus a background job.

How can I design a system such that I can run jobs in the background that are started in the application/domain layer, have them update the database in a specific way to enable the process to continue and react to its completion to, for example, send an email to necessary parties without offloading too much responsibility to an outer layer, infrastructure implementation?

Comment: The background jobs need their own dedicated storage to configure these jobs, including a place to store the current state of the job. Each new job run should be represented by a new record in the job storage. The background service can query this storage periodically for new jobs to run, and then execute them. There are many valid ways to do this, and as such there could be many valid answers, which doesn't fit the format of this site. Can you edit your question to focus on a single problem?

Comment: Im sorry but I really dont understand the issue based on your comment. Many questions (I'd say most) in this field have many "valid" answers - there is rarely a "correct" way to do anything. In fact, I'd say the site is actually ideal for questions with many valid answers, given users can provide many answers. I believe the question is outlined in the final paragraph - what are some ways to design background tasks in an inverted architecture? I personally don't see a way to ask that question and expect a single valid answer.

Comment: The format of this community requires a single focused question with a single answer the community can agree on. This question is asking for a list of ways to design background jobs. No one can write a comprehensive list, which means this question needs focus. The problem isn't that this is an invalid technical question. The problem is that it does not fit the Q&A format of this site.